# php Aes_Encrypt Fatal Error

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, aes

I am inserting the values into the database but i need the password to be encrypted and then insert the special characters to it. I am using mysql database and coding is done in normal php program.

```
PHP PROGRAM


$mysecretkey = 'd5k8b6q3'; 
$password=(AES_ENCRYPT('$v4','$mysecretkey')); // problem is here in encryption 
$q="insert into customers (name,username,email,password) values('$v1','$v2','$v3','$password')";

$s= mysql_query($q); 

                    if(!$s)
                    {
                        $r["re"]="Inserting problem in database";
                        print(json_encode($r));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $r["re"]="Record inserted successfully";
                    }
```

But when i execute the code instead of encrypting it i am getting error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function AES_ENCRYPT() in ..../checking.php on line 5
```

how to solve this problem and other details is the password field in the database is varchar and i am fetching the data from POST variable v1,v2,v3,v4 and test key is added in the above code.

when i give the password as `"test123"` after AES encryption the data has to insert is this `"÷A5jèŸ2A1::h "`

Thanks for your help and time friends........ Please tell how to solve this issue

Comment: You need to put "" around the `AES_ENCRYPT()` part. Also, using the `AES_ENCRYPT` MYSQL function [isn't very secure](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45838/is-why-should-you-avoid-aes-in-mysql-true) by default.

Comment: Sure i will try and let you know my friend @MisterDood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like below (i think it's a mysql function not php so use direct in query)

```
$q="insert into customers (name,username,email,password) values('$v1','$v2','$v3',AES_ENCRYPT('".$v4."','".$mysecretkey."'))";
```

or

```
$q="insert into customers (name,username,email,password) values('$v1','$v2','$v3',AES_ENCRYPT('$v4','$mysecretkey'))";
```

for more :- http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/encryption-and-compression-functions/aes_encrypt%28%29.php

Comment: Thanks i will try and let you know about this .... But i tried the second way which you said it is not working @Rakesh Sharma

Comment: both are some some quoting diff. give try which will work for you

Comment: Ya first one works fine thanks bro i will not forget u in my life. i am sitting from three days and playing with it but u made it in 3 min @Rakesh Sharma

Answer (score 0):

You can try more similar to your approach like

mysql_query("SET @password = AES_ENCRYPT('".$v4."','".$mysecretkey."')");

$q="insert into customers (name,username,email,password) values('$v1','$v2','$v3',@password)";

Comment: gracious words bro i will check it and let u know about this