# Yii2: Using mysql AES_ENCRYPT while inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have got the following error :

> AES_ENCRYPT method not found.

Please help me with using this SQL method in YII2.

```
public function beforeSave($insert) {
        if (!parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            return false;
        }
        if($insert) {
            $this->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }
        $this->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $this->name = AES_ENCRYPT("'.$this->name.'", "SECERT KEY");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: AES_ENCRYPT? Which dbms has that method?

Comment: its mysql @jarlh see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263735/php-aes-encrypt-fatal-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because calling it like

```
$this->name = AES_ENCRYPT("'.$this->name.'", "SECERT KEY");
```

will assume that it is a `php` method and would search in `php` functions available whereas, you need to run it like you do for `CONCAT`, `SUM` or any other `MYSQL` functions.

You should use it with the **`\yii\db\Expression()`** in the following way

```
$enc = new \yii\db\Expression('AES_ENCRYPT("'.$this->name.'","SECERT KEY")');
$this->name=$enc;
```

or simplifying it

```
$this->name=new \yii\db\Expression('AES_ENCRYPT("'.$this->name.'","SECERT KEY")');
```

Hope it helps you out.